Perform aggregation using min,max,avg on all columns
I have a dataframe like
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ ts                  ┆ 646150    ┆ 646151    ┆ 646154    ┆ 646153    ┆ week │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ i8   │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪══════╡
│ 2024-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 24.490348 ┆ 65.088941 ┆ 53.545259 ┆ 13.499832 ┆ 5    │
│ 2024-02-01 01:00:00 ┆ 15.054187 ┆ 63.095247 ┆ 60.786479 ┆ 29.538156 ┆ 5    │
│ 2024-02-01 02:00:00 ┆ 24.54212  ┆ 63.880298 ┆ 57.535928 ┆ 24.840966 ┆ 5    │
│ 2024-02-01 03:00:00 ┆ 24.85621  ┆ 69.778516 ┆ 67.57284  ┆ 24.672476 ┆ 5    │
│ 2024-02-01 04:00:00 ┆ 21.21628  ┆ 61.137849 ┆ 55.231299 ┆ 16.648383 ┆ 5    │
│ …                   ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …    │
│ 2024-02-29 19:00:00 ┆ 23.17318  ┆ 62.590752 ┆ 72.026908 ┆ 24.614523 ┆ 9    │
│ 2024-02-29 20:00:00 ┆ 23.86416  ┆ 64.87102  ┆ 61.023656 ┆ 20.095353 ┆ 9    │
│ 2024-02-29 21:00:00 ┆ 18.553397 ┆ 67.530137 ┆ 63.477737 ┆ 17.313834 ┆ 9    │
│ 2024-02-29 22:00:00 ┆ 22.339175 ┆ 67.456563 ┆ 62.552035 ┆ 20.880844 ┆ 9    │
│ 2024-02-29 23:00:00 ┆ 15.5809   ┆ 66.774367 ┆ 57.066264 ┆ 29.529057 ┆ 9    │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴──────┘

which is generated as follows
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def generate_test_data():
    # Function to generate hourly timestamps for a month
    def generate_hourly_timestamps(start_date, end_date):
        current = start_date
        while current <= end_date:
            yield current
            current += timedelta(hours=1)

    # Define the date range
    start_date = datetime(2024, 2, 1)
    end_date = datetime(2024, 2, 29, 23, 0, 0)  # February 29th 23:00 for a leap year

    # Generate the data
    timestamps = list(generate_hourly_timestamps(start_date, end_date))
    num_hours = len(timestamps)
    data = {
        "ts": timestamps,
        "646150": np.random.uniform(15, 25, num_hours),  # Random temperature data between 15 and 25
        "646151": np.random.uniform(60, 70, num_hours),  # Random humidity data between 60 and 70
        "646154": np.random.uniform(50, 75, num_hours),  # Random sensor data between 50 and 75
        "646153": np.random.uniform(10, 30, num_hours)   # Random sensor data between 10 and 30
    }

    df = pl.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.with_columns(pl.col("ts").cast(pl.Datetime))
    return df


df = generate_test_data()
    
# Add a week column
df = df.with_columns((pl.col("ts").dt.week()).alias("week"))

I would like to group by week or some other time intervals and aggregate using min, mean, and max. For this, I could do something like
# Group by week and calculate min, max, and avg
aggregated_df = df.groupby("week").agg([
    pl.col("646150").min().alias("646150_min"),
    pl.col("646150").max().alias("646150_max"),
    pl.col("646150").mean().alias("646150_avg"),
    pl.col("646151").min().alias("646151_min"),
    pl.col("646151").max().alias("646151_max"),
    pl.col("646151").mean().alias("646151_avg"),
    pl.col("646154").min().alias("646154_min"),
    pl.col("646154").max().alias("646154_max"),
    pl.col("646154").mean().alias("646154_avg"),
    pl.col("646153").min().alias("646153_min"),
    pl.col("646153").max().alias("646153_max"),
    pl.col("646153").mean().alias("646153_avg")
])

but I would like to avoid specifying the column names.
I would like to generate the dataframe like below where the column value is a list or tuples or some other multiple value format that holds the min, max, avg values.
┌─────────────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ week                ┆ 646150           ┆ 646151           │
│ ---                 ┆ ---              ┆ ---              │
│ i8                  ┆ List[f64]        ┆ List[f64]        │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 5                   ┆ [24.1,26.3,25.0] ┆ [22.1,23.3,22.5] │
│ …                   ┆ …                ┆ …                ┆
└─────────────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────┘

Is this possible in polars ?
Thanks

you can do something like this to get struct-typed columns:
df.group_by("week").agg(
    pl.struct(
        pl.col(c).min().alias("min"),
        pl.col(c).max().alias("max"),
        pl.col(c).mean().alias("mean")
    ).alias(c)
    for c in df.columns if c not in ('week', 'ts')
)

┌──────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ week ┆ 646150                    ┆ 646151                    ┆ 646154                    ┆ 646153                    │
│ ---  ┆ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---                       │
│ i8   ┆ struct[3]                 ┆ struct[3]                 ┆ struct[3]                 ┆ struct[3]                 │
╞══════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ 9    ┆ {15.044939,24.764209,20.0 ┆ {60.257012,69.928978,64.7 ┆ {50.530551,74.878361,63.0 ┆ {10.190688,29.82809,20.31 │
│      ┆ 59679…                    ┆ 75548…                    ┆ 78632…                    ┆ 305}                      │
│ 8    ┆ {15.102004,24.991653,20.0 ┆ {60.055959,69.92977,65.01 ┆ {50.048389,74.599839,61.2 ┆ {10.006159,29.938469,20.8 │
│      ┆ 30854…                    ┆ 5284}                     ┆ 97655…                    ┆ 86438…                    │
│ 5    ┆ {15.292633,24.75995,19.50 ┆ {60.068354,69.961624,64.4 ┆ {50.351197,74.665052,62.7 ┆ {10.128425,29.995835,20.5 │
│      ┆ 5275}                     ┆ 92186…                    ┆ 59774…                    ┆ 48913…                    │
│ 7    ┆ {15.054969,24.872284,20.1 ┆ {60.015595,69.978639,65.0 ┆ {50.264015,74.722436,61.2 ┆ {10.058671,29.906661,20.2 │
│      ┆ 02549…                    ┆ 56007…                    ┆ 16711…                    ┆ 89755…                    │
│ 6    ┆ {15.137601,24.97642,19.91 ┆ {60.118846,69.99577,65.32 ┆ {50.025932,74.968677,62.4 ┆ {10.003437,29.798739,19.7 │
│      ┆ 5258}                     ┆ 6988}                     ┆ 8508}                     ┆ 37678…                    │
└──────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘

or, if you want to put it into list:
df.group_by("week").agg(
    pl.concat_list(agg(c) for agg in [pl.min, pl.max, pl.mean])
    for c in df.columns if c not in ('week', 'ts')
)

┌──────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ week ┆ 646150                 ┆ 646151                 ┆ 646154                 ┆ 646153                          │
│ ---  ┆ ---                    ┆ ---                    ┆ ---                    ┆ ---                             │
│ i8   ┆ list[f64]              ┆ list[f64]              ┆ list[f64]              ┆ list[f64]                       │
╞══════╪════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╪════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ 7    ┆ [15.054969, 24.872284, ┆ [60.015595, 69.978639, ┆ [50.264015, 74.722436, ┆ [10.058671, 29.906661, 20.2897… │
│      ┆ 20.1025…               ┆ 65.0560…               ┆ 61.2167…               ┆                                 │
│ 6    ┆ [15.137601, 24.97642,  ┆ [60.118846, 69.99577,  ┆ [50.025932, 74.968677, ┆ [10.003437, 29.798739, 19.7376… │
│      ┆ 19.91525…              ┆ 65.32698…              ┆ 62.4850…               ┆                                 │
│ 5    ┆ [15.292633, 24.75995,  ┆ [60.068354, 69.961624, ┆ [50.351197, 74.665052, ┆ [10.128425, 29.995835, 20.5489… │
│      ┆ 19.50527…              ┆ 64.4921…               ┆ 62.7597…               ┆                                 │
│ 9    ┆ [15.044939, 24.764209, ┆ [60.257012, 69.928978, ┆ [50.530551, 74.878361, ┆ [10.190688, 29.82809, 20.31305… │
│      ┆ 20.0596…               ┆ 64.7755…               ┆ 63.0786…               ┆                                 │
│ 8    ┆ [15.102004, 24.991653, ┆ [60.055959, 69.92977,  ┆ [50.048389, 74.599839, ┆ [10.006159, 29.938469, 20.8864… │
│      ┆ 20.0308…               ┆ 65.01528…              ┆ 61.2976…               ┆                                 │
└──────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘


You can apply an aggregation to all columns using pl.all(), which is just syntactic sugar for pl.col("*"). Moreover, pl.Expr.name.suffix enables you  to add a suffix to the root column name of the expression.
(
    df
    .group_by(pl.col("ts").dt.week(), maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        pl.all().min().name.suffix("_min"),
        pl.all().mean().name.suffix("_mean"),
        pl.all().max().name.suffix("_max"),
    )
)

shape: (5, 13)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬───┬────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ ts  ┆ 646150_min ┆ 646151_min ┆ 646154_min ┆ … ┆ 646150_max ┆ 646151_max ┆ 646154_ma ┆ 646153_ma │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ x         ┆ x         │
│ i8  ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆   ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│     ┆            ┆            ┆            ┆   ┆            ┆            ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 5   ┆ 15.177066  ┆ 60.032106  ┆ 50.067449  ┆ … ┆ 24.841566  ┆ 69.800279  ┆ 74.982663 ┆ 29.922882 │
│ 6   ┆ 15.020478  ┆ 60.023451  ┆ 50.082165  ┆ … ┆ 24.972867  ┆ 69.987384  ┆ 74.767396 ┆ 29.953051 │
│ 7   ┆ 15.053958  ┆ 60.034569  ┆ 50.15529   ┆ … ┆ 24.990647  ┆ 69.97015   ┆ 74.923963 ┆ 29.725695 │
│ 8   ┆ 15.00012   ┆ 60.017424  ┆ 50.188615  ┆ … ┆ 24.969808  ┆ 69.961523  ┆ 74.921852 ┆ 29.907943 │
│ 9   ┆ 15.008807  ┆ 60.076137  ┆ 50.149467  ┆ … ┆ 24.979337  ┆ 69.993334  ┆ 73.715043 ┆ 29.639696 │
└─────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴───┴────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


If you did a "wide to long" reshape with .unpivot()
df.drop("ts").unpivot(index="week")

shape: (40, 3)
┌──────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ week ┆ variable ┆ value     │
│ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ i8   ┆ str      ┆ f64       │
╞══════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 5    ┆ 646150   ┆ 24.490348 │
│ 5    ┆ 646150   ┆ 15.054187 │
│ …    ┆ …        ┆ …         │
│ 9    ┆ 646153   ┆ 24.614523 │
│ 9    ┆ 646153   ┆ 20.095353 │
└──────┴──────────┴───────────┘

It could also be expressed in terms of .pivot()
(df.drop("ts")
   .unpivot(index="week")
   .pivot(
      on = "variable",
      index = "week",
      aggregate_function = pl.struct(
         min = pl.element().min(),
         max = pl.element().max(),
         mean = pl.element().mean()
      )
   )
)

shape: (2, 5)
┌──────┬────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ week ┆ 646150                         ┆ 646151                          ┆ 646154                         ┆ 646153                          │
│ ---  ┆ ---                            ┆ ---                             ┆ ---                            ┆ ---                             │
│ i8   ┆ struct[3]                      ┆ struct[3]                       ┆ struct[3]                      ┆ struct[3]                       │
╞══════╪════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╡
│ 5    ┆ {15.054187,24.85621,22.031829} ┆ {61.137849,69.778516,64.59617}  ┆ {53.545259,67.57284,58.934361} ┆ {13.499832,29.538156,21.839963… │
│ 9    ┆ {15.5809,23.86416,20.702162}   ┆ {62.590752,67.530137,65.844568… ┆ {57.066264,72.026908,63.22932} ┆ {17.313834,29.529057,22.486722… │
└──────┴────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘


Very elegant avoiding manual iteration over columns like this!
